# How to change android package name where there is middle name missing?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know how to change the package name, suppose from `com.example.abc` to `com.xyz.abc` but here in my project the package name is `com.abc` and I want to change it to `com.xyz.abc`. How can I do that on Android Studio? Could someone help me with it?

This question is not a duplicate of another post that was linked to it as in my case there is no middle name.

My question differs from the other questions that were linked to my post, in my case there is no middle name. Anyways, I have already fixed the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637004/2408342).

Comment: Can I ask why the linked post doesn't work for you?  It shouldn't matter that there's a middle name, you should be able to rename the package the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a package `xyz` under `com` folder. Then Move all the directory which is inside `com` folder to `xyz` folder.

Comment: I get the following error when I rebuild the project. `> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.xyz.abc'`

Comment: OK, I fixed it. I have to change the package name in the google-services.json file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `xyz` to `abc`. You will have `com.abc.abc`. Refactor > Move all files from child `abc` to parent `abc` folder. Finally, delete child `abc` folder.